# ReactJS Component not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'am very new in the programming world and React (using the COVID-19 time to get better...). I'm trying to render a component when the user is clicking a register button. My goal is to display it as a pop-up in the middle of the screen for the user to fill a form. (I'm using Visual studio code and react app generator)

I can't make it happen, if I console.log the result true/false ( depending on a condition) it works correctly so I guess the problem is the way I " call" the component.

If anyone could point toward the good direction I would glady appreciate !

The App class where the handler function is calling the supposed popup div

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "./UI/Header";import RegisterWindow from "./UI/RegisterWindow"; import Footer from "./UI/Footer"; import MainSection from "./UI/MainSection";
import "./index.css"


class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state ={
      registerIsShowed: false
    }
    this.handleRegister = this.handleRegister.bind(this)
  }

  handleRegister(){
   this.setState({
     registerIsShowed: !this.state.registerIsShowed
   })
   const isShowed = this.state.registerIsShowed;
   return isShowed ? <RegisterWindow /> : null
  }

render(){
return (
  <div>
    <Header register={this.handleRegister} />
    <MainSection />
  </div>
)}

}


export default App
```

This is the Header code where the button that triggers the opening is located

```
import React from "react"

function Header(props) {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="navbar-header">
        <p className="header-data"></p>
        <ul className="navbar-menu-header">
          <li><button onClick={props.register}>Registrar</button></li>
          <li><button>Entrar</button></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

and finally the Component that is supposed to show up

```
import React from "react"

class RegisterWindow extends React.Component{
render(){
  return (
    <div className="register-window">
      <div>
        <form>
          <input name="firstName" placeholder="First name" type="text" />First Name
          <input name="lasttName" placeholder="Last name" type="text" />Last Name
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
}


export default RegisterWindow
```

thank you,

Comment: `onClick` does not expect a return value. It's a common mistake for beginners. How would react know where it should be rendered? You need to include the `RegisterWindow` component directly in the render and show or hide it there (sometimes with an if...else, sometimes with a ternary, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RegisterWindow` component must be included in the Render lifecycle function in a class component, or within a return statement of a functional component.  Your `App` component is class based so it must contain a `render()` method.

Setting the state is asynchronous, so even if you could render the component from the `handleRegister()` callback in a class component, the state update wouldn't be immediate so your synchronous logic to display the `RegisterWindow` component would fail.

Try something like this:

```
handleRegister() {
  this.setState({
    registerIsShowed: !this.state.registerIsShowed
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <>
      {this.state.registerIsShowed && <RegisterWindow />}

      <div>
        <Header register={this.handleRegister} />
        <MainSection />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

`this.state.registerIsShowed && <RegisterWindow />` is an example of **[Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)**.

To make the `RegisterWindow` appear floating above the `MainSection`, you can style it with an absolute position.

Comment: Thank you ! I understand the logic behind it now. it's working correctly now !